# Android MediaPlayer shows error after Phone call is ended

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager, telephonymanager

I am developing an App in Android to play videos. I need to deal with the event of losing audio focus for the App. So I am testing the interruption caused by an incoming phone call to the MediaPlayer playing a video.

When the phone rings and if the user rejects the call, the phone interruption disappears and the MediaPlayer regains its previous volume. Fine

When the phone rings and if the user accepts the incoming phone call, I programmed a MediaPlayer.pause() in the onPause() callback. It triggers Ok and the video is correctly paused.

But the problem arises when the user terminates the phone call: then MediaPlayer shows an error 100 and playback cannot resume from pause.

My log could reveal something:

```
D/AudioManager: AudioManager dispatching onAudioFocusChange(-2) for android.media.AudioManager@954b834com.languagematerial.lmmovies.LMMoviesMainActivity$1@56a765d
W/AudioSystem: AudioFlinger server died!
W/MediaMetadataRetriever: MediaMetadataRetriever server died!
W/IMediaDeathNotifier: media server died
E/MediaPlayer: error (100, 0)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (100,0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf254480: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaf267b60)
E/MediaPlayer: stop called in state 0
           error (-38, 0)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf254480: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaf267b60)
I/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI: native_setup
V/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI: setDataSource
I/MediaMetadataRetrieverJNI: release
W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (3, 0)
E/MediaPlayer: internal/external state mismatch corrected
W/IMediaDeathNotifier: media server died
E/MediaPlayer: error (100, 0)
W/MediaMetadataRetriever: MediaMetadataRetriever server died!
E/MediaPlayer: Error (100,0)
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa1542dc0
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf254480: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaf267b60)
D/AudioManager: AudioManager dispatching onAudioFocusChange(1) for android.media.AudioManager@954b834com.languagematerial.lmmovies.LMMoviesMainActivity$1@56a765d
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xaf254480: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xaf267b60)
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa1542be0
```

I already implemented a Listener for the AudioFocusChange, like this:

```
ojbGloOnAudioFocusChangeListener = new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAudioFocusChange(int audiofocusChangeInt) {
            switch (audiofocusChangeInt) {
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
                    play();
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT:
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK:
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
                    pause();
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT: // Here when phone call is ringing, not yet answered. Ringing implies that the sound focus of the mediaplayer is already snatched
                    pause();
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
                    break;
                case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_FAILED:
                    break;
                default:
            }
        }
    };
```

When the phone call ends, it does enter the Listener with the value: **AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN**. So it means that Android tries to give back the AudioFocus to my App, the problem is that when it goes into the Listener, the MediaPlayer is already in Error and play() wont work.

If the problem is not the AudioFocus, what else could it be?
By the way, the only way to avoid the Error condition is if I stop COMPLETELY the MediaPlayer: (which is absurd)

```
MediaPlayer.stop(); 
MediaPlayer.reset();
MediaPlayer.release();
MediaPlayer = null;
```

So, any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved! This page gave me the solution: [Create a Music Player on Android: User Controls](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-music-player-on-android-user-controls--mobile-22787)

You just have to add this code to the callback overridden function: **onError**:

```
@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
  mp.reset();
  return false;
}
```

Now you just continue your playback in the AudioFocus Listener:

```
objGloOnAudioFocusChangeListener = new AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int audiofocusChangeInt) {
        switch (audiofocusChangeInt) {
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
                yourMediaPlayer.play();
                break;   ...}}
```

Saludos!